# RMarkdown does not show the output

Tags: r, r-markdown

i am really sorry if some one already asked this question, but I can not find it.
My problem is that I want to create a PDF using RMardown. But all it does is showing the code, but no results. I am already trying for 1 hour.

```
 {r setup, include=FALSE}
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)



{r include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
data_fed<-read_csv("fd-cross.csv")





{r Aufgabe1, message=FALSE}

MY CODE
```

Comment: In this case, substituting "MY CODE", for your actual code won't help us to figure out what is wrong with your code.

Comment: You need to remove `include=FALSE`, that is why your code is not being displayed. Also make sure you have the 3 backticks in your r code chunks \```r{}```